# how to sort and limit aggregations in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

For example I have the following records with the columns as:(Country,City,Date,Income)

```
USA SF 2015-08 50
USA SF 2015-05 30
USA SF 2015-01 20
USA NY 2015-05 70
USA NY 2015-02 10
U.K LD 2015-05 90
```

My sql as: `select country,city,max(date) as maxDate,sum(income) as sumIncome from testTable group by country,city order by maxDate desc,sumIncome desc limit 3`.
So the result should be:

```
USA SF 2015-08 100
U.K LD 2015-05 90
USA NY 2015-05 80
```

I wrote the ES aggregates as following, but it's wrong:

```
"aggs":{"sub1": {"terms":{"field":"contry"},
   "aggs":{"sub2":{"terms":{"field":"city",
       "order":[{"submax":"DESC"},{"subsum":"DESC"}]},
     "aggs":{"submax":{"max":{"field":"date"}},"subsum":{"sum":{"field":"income"}}}}}}}
```

By my above script, it got the wrong result as following:

```
USA SF 2015-08 100
USA NY 2015-05 80
U.K LD 2015-05 90
```

Comment: ES is not a relational database. An SQL query doesn't always give you the same result, in the same form in ES.

Comment: Thanks Andrei, But I believe ES can do the above sql, just I'm still a beginner of ES :)

Comment: Any ideas please? I'm really stuck here, headache...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You, actually, have two options, now that I understood the requirement.

**Option 1**

Use a `script` to "concatenate" `country` field and `city` field. Using the regular aggregations per field to do what you want is not possible in Elasticsearch.

Instead you need to do something like this:

```
GET /test/test/_search?search_type=count
{
  "aggs": {
    "sub1": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "doc['country'].value + ' ' + doc['city'].value",
        "size": 3,  
        "order": [
          {
            "submax": "DESC"
          },
          {
            "subsum": "DESC"
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "submax": {
          "max": {
            "field": "date"
          }
        },
        "subsum": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "income"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With `curl`:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/livebox/type1/_search?search_type=count" -d'
{
  "aggs": {
    "sub1": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "doc[\"boxname\"].value + \" \" + doc[\"app\"].value",
        "size": 3,
        "order": [
          {
            "submax": "DESC"
          },
          {
            "subsum": "DESC"
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "submax": {
          "max": {
            "field": "date"
          }
        },
        "subsum": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "count"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

And the result of the aggregation will generate terms that are of the following form: `country` +  + `city`.

```
     "buckets": [
        {
           "key": "usa sf",
           "doc_count": 3,
           "subsum": {
              "value": 100
           },
           "submax": {
              "value": 1438387200000,
              "value_as_string": "2015-08"
           }
        },
        {
           "key": "uk ld",
           "doc_count": 1,
           "subsum": {
              "value": 90
           },
           "submax": {
              "value": 1430438400000,
              "value_as_string": "2015-05"
           }
        },
        {
           "key": "usa ny",
           "doc_count": 2,
           "subsum": {
              "value": 80
           },
           "submax": {
              "value": 1430438400000,
              "value_as_string": "2015-05"
           }
        }
     ]
```

**Option 2**

Use [`_source` transformation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/mapping-transform.html#mapping-transform) that will build a new field at *indexing* time, which will "move" the performance impact of running a script at aggregation time.

The mapping of the index, as it needs some changes, whatever you have now:

```
PUT /test
{
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "transform": {
        "script": "ctx._source['country_and_city'] = ctx._source['country'] + ' ' + ctx._source['city']"
      },
      "properties": {
        "country": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "city": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "income": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "date": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "yyyy-MM"
        },
        "country_and_city": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The query:

```
GET /test/test/_search?search_type=count
{
  "aggs": {
    "sub1": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "country_and_city",
        "order": [
          {
            "submax": "DESC"
          },
          {
            "subsum": "DESC"
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "submax": {
          "max": {
            "field": "date"
          }
        },
        "subsum": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "income"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the result:

```
     "buckets": [
        {
           "key": "usa sf",
           "doc_count": 3,
           "subsum": {
              "value": 100
           },
           "submax": {
              "value": 1438387200000,
              "value_as_string": "2015-08"
           }
        },
        {
           "key": "uk ld",
           "doc_count": 1,
           "subsum": {
              "value": 90
           },
           "submax": {
              "value": 1430438400000,
              "value_as_string": "2015-05"
           }
        },
        {
           "key": "usa ny",
           "doc_count": 2,
           "subsum": {
              "value": 80
           },
           "submax": {
              "value": 1430438400000,
              "value_as_string": "2015-05"
           }
        }
     ]
```

Comment: thank you Andrei, unfortunately it doesn't work. The above script would only sort in each country rather sort by country&city.

Comment: So, you mean that you want to have `USA NY 2015-09 100 |||
USA SF 2015-05 160 ||| CAN OT 2015-05 150 ||| USA WA 2015-02 100`? Meaning the countries intertwined?

Comment: I modified the question with right and wrong results. And I set the limit is 3 instead of 2.

Comment: thanks a lot for your awesome solution, but I met an error when running the curl script, the error msg as following: GroovyScriptExecutionException[MissingPropertyException[No such property: country for class: Script8]]

Comment: the following is my query:curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/livebox/type1/_search?search_type=count' -d '{"aggs": {"sub1": {"terms": {"script": "doc['boxname'].value+doc['app'].value","size": 3,"order": [{"submax": "DESC"},{"subsum": "DESC"}]},"aggs": {"submax": {"max": {"field": "date"}},"subsum": {"sum": {"field": "count"}}}}}}'     --since this is production environment so it has different field names. I removed +' '+ since it cause syntax error. btw, I'm using elastic search 1.5.2

Comment: ... ok and for this `curl` you have another exception, because it's not clear from your message?

Comment: Did it work in the end? Do you still experience issues?

Comment: I think your solution should be right, but when I ran the script it threw the exception: No such property doc['country']. I didn't typo, in dev I used country and City, in prod environment I used other name.

Comment: Can you provide the complete mapping (use a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) if it's easier for you) of the index you tried this on?

Comment: yes, I will provide the mapping and query tomorrow. Thank you so much!

Comment: It works for me :-(. And in 1.5.2. But I wonder why you had to remove `' '`. This sounds like a syntax error maybe? Can you try all these things in [Marvel's Sense dashboard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/marvel/current/dashboards.html#sense)? (bypassing curl) If you don't already use Marvel, it's [easy to install](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/marvel/current/_installation.html#_simple_install).

Comment: Btw, I've added a different `curl` syntax in my response. Try that.

Comment: Thank you so much Andrei, your solutions are awesome! I really appreciate!

Comment: did  you get the 50 bounty, I don't know how do I give the bounty to you. If you still not get the bounty please let me know, thanks a again!

Comment: I indexed 1TB data and tested a single field query.  I'm surprised that the query performance of Option1 is faster than Option2, I supposed Option2 should be faster, what do you think please :)

Comment: Interesting, I would have thought the same.